# Why Nginx location /dir/ does not work for /dir/ itself, but works for any /dir/file?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Please, explain me why this part in NGINX

```
location /a/b/ {
  return 429;  #error for debug  
}
```

works only for URLs like `https://example.com/a/b/something` but not for `https://example.com/a/b/`

Adding get parameters or # anchor changes nothing.

### Update: Other config parts

```
location /dev/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8009/;
    proxy_redirect  http://$host/ /dev/;
}

# This is my current workaround
location = /dev2/editor/ {
    alias /editor_html_root/;
}

# This is the place that I ask about
location /dev2/editor/ {
    alias /editor_html_root/;
}

location /dev2/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8011/;
    proxy_redirect  http://$host/ /dev2/;
}
```

Comment: That `location` matches both URIs **but only if** there are no other `location` or `rewrite` rules that override it. We would need to see the entire `server` block to understand. The `#` part of a URI is never sent to the server.

Comment: @RichardSmith I've the same idea but I can't figure out which rule cound do this. Config added to questiuon.

Comment: The usual reason that a prefix `location` fails to match, is that a regular expression `location` takes precedence. Are there any regular expression `location` blocks in your config?